# StackExchange Password Reset deleted previous posts

Tags: discussion

For some reason my password didn't work after I logged out. I had made some posts. I did a password reset and now my previous posts are totally gone.  But everything else, the profile, etc.. was there.

Comment: Do you know what posts you had? I see one deleted answer on your profile.

Comment: It was a reply to someone's post because I had the same problem. Then I went back in and edited the post.  I'm having trouble with rsyslog logging and logrotate.

Answer (score 2):

[Your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/574813/44179) was deleted in due process because it was posted in the answer section but was not an attempt to answer the question (or if it was an attempted answer it was very hard to tell).  The answer section is reserved for actual answers to the question, nothing else.

There [is](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment) a comment privilege (at 50 rep) it isn't meant to be used for "me too" like comments, but rather information useful in the answering of the question (but not full answers!) or requesting clarification.

I know this can be very confusing for someone new to our format, but Stack Exchange operates very differently from a forum (we don't even call ourselves one). A lot of helpful information regarding this can be found in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help).